# No Android é possível inflar um layout dentro de uma gridview

Tags: android, gridview

Estou tentando criar um leitor de e-book, na Activity principal deve aparecer um gridview onde cada posição deve apresentar uma miniatura da capa do livro, embaixo apareça o nome do livro, nome do autor e data de publicação: oque eu espero é algo desse tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

obs.:Favor desconsiderar as estrelas e o botão de opções só preciso da imagem e os três textos.

no momento estou utilizando um Gridview, para coloar dentro de cada posição um Linear layout que contém um imageview e três textview.

A minha pergunta é: Posso inflar um layout dentro de um gridview ou existe outra maneira de fazer o que estou pretendendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor solução nesse caso é utilizar [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) e [GridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html).

O RecyclerView funciona como um ListView, ou seja, você precisará de um Adapter. Este [Tutorial](http://ediposouza.com/recycling-view-o-novo-listview-do-android) em português mostra como você pode utilizar o RecyclerView. Ele utiliza LinearLayoutManager. No seu caso, você irá utilizar o GridLayoutManager.